# Can anyone explain the cloud function to a newbie?

Tags: python-3.x, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-platform

Sorry, if this question is not for this site of professionals but I found no other better place to ask this. 
I went through some google documents but honestly couldn't understand how to write a cloud function for my requirements. To give you what I want, this is an overview: I wrote a python script to extract the required data from Firebase but then how to proceed towards the Cloud function? This is the script I have written to get the required data:

```
ref=db.reference('agents')
snapshot = ref.order_by_key().get()
#print(len(snapshot))
for key, val in snapshot.items():
    kw=val
    dictfilt = lambda x, y: dict([ (i,x[i]) for i in x if i in set(y) ])
    wanted_keys = ("address","email","name")
    result = dictfilt(kw, wanted_keys)
    #print(result)
    serialized= json.dumps(result, sort_keys=True)`
```

Now how to write a cloud function and trigger from here? Can anyone please put their precious time to respond and explain to this newbie? Thank you!

Comment: I came across this script on github but got no idea about the arguments data and context. Anyway, I tried but it showed error maybe I did in a wrong way? https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/functions/firebase/main.py

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap all this in a single function, then determine:

1. How it will be triggered (either by HTTP or by an event like Pub/Sub)
2. What the response should look like

For example, if this was to be an HTTP trigger, the function would take a `request` parameter, and return a string or JSON:

```py
def your_function(request):

    # Your code goes here
    ref=db.reference('agents')
    snapshot = ref.order_by_key().get()
    #print(len(snapshot))
    for key, val in snapshot.items():
        kw=val
        dictfilt = lambda x, y: dict([ (i,x[i]) for i in x if i in set(y) ])
        wanted_keys = ("address","email","name")
        result = dictfilt(kw, wanted_keys)
        #print(result)
    serialized= json.dumps(result, sort_keys=True)`

    # Return something as a response
    return ...
```

Comment: Thanks @Dustin for  making it clear to me! I try to wrap it up as you mentioned but got error messages! I used the http trigger command i.e., "gcloud functions deploy function_name --runtime python37 --trigger-http" but it says: "ERROR: gcloud crashed (BadStatusLine): ''"

Comment: Now, I can deploy my function but again it's not doing the thing what I want and throwing me error saying: "Error: could not handle the request". In log record, it's saying :"NameError: name 'credentials' is not defined". I put the jso authentication file of Firebase in "  cred = credentials.Certificate(path to json file)"

Comment: This is how my function looks like: https://pastebin.com/998hiz8p              Did I miss anything?